# How to edit external library for android studio 3.1.2?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, android-library

I'm trying to edit a external library base of answers in here, but it's not working on android studio 3.1.2(which it's the version i'm using).

Base on what people said, i should get library from github, import module.
I want to change digits of this [Elegant Button](https://github.com/ashik94vc/ElegantNumberButton/tree/development) library.

So what i did was I've downloaded this library with download/zip, then `File > new > Import Module` and did some configuration and decencies and still it's not working. looks like these method won't work with new version of android studio. can anyone explain how to edit with android studio 3.1.2?

[image]

Comment: `File > new > Import Module` is not a method . These are steps to add a project as module . Once you have project as module you can make changes in its code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Editing external libraries in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48635049/editing-external-libraries-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add external library to project

Steps:

Unzip the file

Go to **Android studio** - **File** - **New Import Module**

Import the module and click OK

Once you added the library add the library to app gradle also

```
implementation project(path: ':library-name')
```

Comment: how can i edit library i've named at top? how can i download the library code to edit it? i guess the reason that i've failed is because i've download zip in github page.

Comment: there is no problem with zip ,its a project you need to unzip the above project and import the library folder which used in this project..

Comment: i've added a image, please check and tell me what to choose, i've choosed lib once, and nothing happened.

Comment: yeah i can see the screeshot as i said dont import full project only import the library name as lib in this project ....you are importig the full project thats doesnt make sense