# Import module on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-module

I've got a problem on library importation.
I followed these step :

1. File / New / Import Module.
2. Then I go to Project structure, Dependencies and "+". But there is Nothing to show.

Is somebody can help me ?

Screen : https://i.stack.imgur.com/B72EM.jpg

Comment: Show your project view in Android Studio?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/fBbCkll

Comment: On Left top corner, there is a project option where **Android** is selected. Change it to **Project** and upload a new image

Comment: HLS is here : https://imgur.com/a/8zGKDQ3

Comment: Which version of Android Studio are are you using?

Comment: Using Android studio 3.1.2

Comment: Use `implementation` instead of `compile` and update the library versions to the latest. Then sync the project.

Comment: You'll see hls in the **Dependencies** tab, once you fix the gradle sync.

Comment: Also, exoplayer supports Java8. So, your project needs to support java8 too.

Comment: @Arnaud check my answer and tell me if it helps you getting what you want.

Answer (score 1):

In order to add library module in your project you should follow the following steps:

1) After adding library, open your project's build.gradle file and add `implementation project(path: ':yourLibraryName')`.

2) Don't sync yet, now open your settings.gradle file and add your project with your library: `include  ':yourLibrayName', ':yourProject/ModuleName'`. Now sync.

3) After sync you will be able to use your library in your project.

Answer (score 1):

Go to main menu -> File -> New -> Import Module. Then select the source code. Give module a name. (Android studio 3.3)

Add following line to app build.gradle

```
implementation project(':module_name')
```

Also in the settings.gradle file should have following line

```
  include ':app'
  include ':module_name'
```

[image: Import module]

Answer (score 0):

try : go to SDK manager-> SDK tools : look for Support repository and download them
this might work

Comment: This is a specific library from exoplayer what I need to add.

Comment: Yes, I've download the repo, take HLS library, adding it via File / New / Import Module (and it worked). But nothing appear in project structure, or in depency tab.

Comment: have you downloaded repo externally and now you want to add in gradle? or what?

Comment: At the start, I just want update my exoplayer project from 2.8.4 to 2.9.
But, I get this error : ERROR: HlsSampleStreamWrapper.java:174-175: Lambda coming from jar file need their interfaces on the classpath to be compiled, unknown interfaces are java.lang.Runnable

As I understant, I need to add HLS library from exoplayer repo.

Comment: okay Change your project view from Android to Project; your will find it at top of android studio. then there will be a repo named "external lib"

Comment: add this in gradle compileOptions {
  targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

Comment: add this in gradle compileOptions { targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 }

Comment: Added targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 + JackOptions Enabled

Answer (score 0):

You need to add import module in **gradle** also

Try this

**implementation project(path: ':yourLibName')**

than sync it  will show dependencies.

Comment: Added implementation project(path: ':hls') but does not works : 
Project with path ':hls' could not be found in project ':app'.

Comment: gradle  synced  properly?

Comment: no, it give me this error : Project with path ':hls' could not be found in project ':app'.

Comment: its mean your lib not added in your project ...just remove lib for now and add module again to follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51894689/how-to-edit-external-library-for-android-studio-3-1-2/51894832#51894832