# Disable Toast on Android

Tags: android, android-toast

I have added a library, It is showing a toast message every time the app start. How to disable this toast. Any hack method also be appreciated.

**I am unable to modify library code it is a classpath dependency**
[image]

Comment: Can you share what you have done already?

Comment: i dont know how to do it, so I have not done anything already. Do you know how to do it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Editing external libraries in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48635049/editing-external-libraries-in-android-studio)

Comment: i have already mentioned it is a classpath dependency . do you know how to edit it @Tausif

Comment: How do you know that is it from classpath dependency ? can you please show us in which scenario this is occurred ?

Comment: how do you know it is not..as I am 100% sure that's why  I have mentioned it. Noob...if you know how to edit classpath library just tell me..why you are more concerned about whether toast is coming from that library..

Comment: Please research more, invest more time. Hope, one day you get the solution. 
Thanks !

Comment: Please update your question title and  ask "How to edit classpath library code or class". It will be more meaningful for us to understand.

Comment: my concern is to just disable toast and it is in top priority, that's why it is in the title, modifying classpath is one of the ways to do it.. anyone in the community can also answer any other way to disable toast.

Comment: You would need to talk to the developers of the Gradle plugin that you are using from that library and ask them how to disable this `Toast`.

Answer (score -1):

Override the library, without the Toast

Comment: i have already mentioned it  is a classpath dependency . do you know how to edit it