# I can't Import Module from Source, The Finish button is off

Tags: android, android-studio, import, module, import-module

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcZoL.png)i want to use this module or other modules, the finish button is off. anyone has a same situation like me?

[https://github.com/mohamad-amin/PersianMaterialDateTimePicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThpI3.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it is a bug in android studio arctic fox.
Google didn't response with any solution but for now you can do:

```
 1. copy your-module folder in your project directory.
 2.  Add below line in settings.gradle.
 3. include ':your-module' // your-module is module name.
 4. click sync now
```

Comment: This bug was solved in the new update. Update your android studio to solve this problem.