# Importing external library with different gradle files

Tags: android, android-studio

I wanted to edit the source code of an external library.

According to [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48635049/editing-external-libraries-in-android-studio) instructions (I have chosen method 2) and have stuck at
step 3.
First I imported it with the libraries gradle files and it corrupted my project.
So, I had a backup and started again. Now, I deleted all the gradle files in that library.
But now it wants some gradle file to be there.

The external library is [here](https://github.com/chimbori/crux/archive/refs/tags/v3.5.0.zip) . How can I correctly import it to my Android Studio project, to be able to edit its source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [method 2 of your referenced answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48635089/6309) should still apply.

The [Crux library](https://github.com/chimbori/crux) is single module library.
You can try and create a new folder "`Crux`" in your project's main directory, adding the content of the library there.
I would recommend to clone a fork of the Crux repository instead, through a [`git submodule add`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309) if you want to make changes in it.

`git submodule add -- https://github.com/me/crux Crux`: that will create the `Crux` folder.
(replace "me" with your GitHub account name, after forking the original `chimbori/crux` repository)

Add a `3.5.0` branch to the v3.5.0 tagged commit, in order to do a `git submodule set-branch --branch 3.5.0 -- Crux`.

```bash
cd Crux
git switch -c 3.5.0 v3.5.0
git submodule set-branch --branch 3.5.0 -- Crux
```

Your `settings.gradle` file would then include:

```
include ':app', ':Crux'
```

Do a [`gradle sync`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29565263/6309) and ensure that the build is successful.

Edit your project's `build.gradle` to add this in the "`dependencies`" section:

```
dependencies {
    //...
    implementation project(':Crux')
}
```

That should allow you to edit the Crux library code as you want, directly within your project.